# Help in solution more than one form in asp.net as to my logic its compulsory

Tags: asp.net, forms, runatserver

As per my layout one form(all forms with runat=server) should be in header right top and
the other one I want to place in section's article. So I will have no problem in positioning of contents. How do I solve it?

My design: Login & logout are contained in form at header top-right;

article:Embedding AJAX4 accordian & tab container
but this requires it to be placed in form as `<asp:scriptManager` should be in form having `runat=server`.

(article has aside_left & aside_right near to it seperated and header at top seperated which contains the form)

So any Solution for this?

Do I have to change the logic?

I am working with visual studio 2010 asp.net 4 IIS v6 of windows7 x86

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you are asking about. Are you asking for CSS placement tips or something?

Comment: I formulated an awnser but I'm not 100% sure I understand the question myself. Is the problem the layout, or having more than one form on the page ?

Comment: You can have one form having runat="server" but many other forms without specifying runat="server" on a page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can do what you are looking for with Master pages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

Create a master page with a content section for the header and another for the rest of the page. The create pages for both of those content sections.

Comment: No but how to place ajaxstuff(accordian) in form_article and also place ajaxstuff at form_header but both are not possible at one time as runtime error is (say form_article has runat) then ajaxstuff of form_header should be placed in a form having runat=server          <br /> Control 'TabContainer_bookings' of type 'TabContainer' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: @prakash: Ok so the question is how to use AJAX controls on two different forms on the same ASP.Net page ?

Comment: @prakash: Are all the controls on one page? Then you should place them all within one `form` with `runat="server"`.

Comment: my code: master page:  <header> <form runat>ajax contenet prefixed by *script manager*</header>           <article><form>ajax content_2 </article>               problem is : it says ajax content_2 should be in form having runat => ajax content_2 should be in form1 but i want Ajax_content_2 in article itself  . I hope im clear

Comment: @prakash: You shouldn't need the 2nd form as you already have a form with `runat="server"` in your master page.

Comment: If i place all stuff in one form doesn't it adds load or atleast hard to apply css of course possible. But if no other solution i will go by ur way> actually i did not get ur idea i was only thinking how to do my idea which had no solution. Anyway if no other solution found i will go by ur way . Thanks for alternate solution. Thanku and any other idea too?

Comment: @prakash: You show do like Town just said 2 comments up and place them all on one form. If you really can't have them both in two differents forms, I would still try MasterPages. When you define your ContentPages, you can have one form with the RunAtServer attribute on both content pages.

Comment: @prakash: I've updated my answer with a example implementation.  You can add an additional ContentPlaceHolder in the `<head>` of your master page, which will allow you to include styles that are specific to your content pages.

Comment: as u said i dont need 2nd form with runat="server" but if i dont add runat it says the runtime error : the tab container should be place in a form tag with runat=server

Comment: @prakash: I think you may need to post some code.  Considering you've already said the Master Page form has `runat="server"` defined, then it sounds like maybe the content page is just a standard `aspx` page that isn't referencing the master page.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need a [MasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) containing your login and logout buttons, and then a content page containing your 'article'.

**Master page (.master)**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

        <!-- login / logout controls here -->

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Article" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </form>
```

**Content page (.aspx):**

```
<asp:Content ID="ArticleContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Article" runat="server">

<!-- Accordion and things here -->

</asp:Content>
```

If that's not what you're after, then [this link](http://www.frederikvig.com/2009/06/using-multiple-forms-on-an-asp-net-web-forms-page/) provides details on how to implement multiple forms on a page in ASP.NET.

Comment: Yes now i can explain: in .master the thing <!-- ** --> i want it in <header> of html5 and the 2nd <asp: in <article> of html5. So .master is <header><asp:CPH> </header> <section><article><asp:cph2></section>     .contenetPage <content1><form having login stuff></content1>  <content2><form>accordian & tab AJAX STUFF <form></content2>

Comment: @prakash: you listed a lot of things that you're working with in your original question - It might be worth adding 'HTML5' to that list... Anyway, you've got two forms in there. You want one, in your master page.

Comment: @prakash: Also, post the code in the original question.  If you can copy/paste the code in and format it as a code block in the editor then it'll make it much easier to decypher.

Comment: Sir i think the best solution now after discusion i found is not to try to convert an object to int i.e., follow the best widely use methods than strucking in coceptually wrong ideas. So i will use the two options u have provided 1>Place entire contents in form 2>to try ur master page thing(im already doing in master page though but i will try to find where i went wrong).   Is there any way i can upload to u my two of these text files with only data that is required rather than putting u to stuff of understanding whole site.

Comment: @prakash: if you just paste in the key bits, like you've written in your first comment here but copy/pasted from your actual code.  Basically, if you place your `<form runat="server">` tag around all the place holders then any controls within those place holders will be automatically contained within the form.  As this is your first time here, if you're happy with the answer don't forget to click the tick :)

Comment: <%@ Master %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<header>
    <img/>
    <h2>Restaurant Gets Flexible</h2>
    <form id="header_form" method="post" action="Default.aspx" runat="server" > <!-- here form with runat -->
        login stuff and some ajax: updatPanel
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
</header>
<section>
    <aside id="aside_left"></asi>
    <article> <!--here: i want to place AJAX STUFF tab container -->
        <asp:CPH id="ContentPlaceHolder_article" runat="server">article</asp:C>
    </art>
</sec>

Comment: Booking.aspx
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content_booking" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_article" Runat="Server">
    <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer_bookings" runat="server" form="header_form">
        <asp:TabPanel>
            <HeaderTemplate>Booking Table</HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>Here accordian to book table<br />Or using wizard</ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel><TabP2>
    </asp:TabC>
</asp:Content>

Comment: Let Me try out things which u people said and i will report u soon. Thanku and if u can edit my code to appear properly that would be good. Thanks see u soon

Comment: @prakash : you can edit your original question rather than pasting your code as a comment. In the code you've pasted your closing </form> tag needs to be after the closing </ContentPlaceHolder>.